# How to identify different duplicate records in an excel file for certain IDs but across different Events using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a situation where I have an excel file with different columns containing IDs of certain individuals who are asked to speak different words (Column: **Dialogue**) on different occasions (Column: **Event**) carried out across different dates (Column: **Date**).

The table appears somewhat like this:

[image]

Now I want to sort out those those records in which *duplication of* **Date** and **Dialogue** is there across different Events.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Please suggest me how to do the same using pandas package of python.

Kindly don't mark this question as a duplicate without seeing it first. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

you can try:

```
#check If value is duplicated or not:
m=df.duplicated(subset=['Date','Dialogue'],keep=False)

#Finally:
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

Comment: Dear @Anurag Dabas

There are more columns in the table that I forgot to specify (but the duplication of records will only depend upon **Date** and **Dialogue** values. I regret my mistake.

Can you please explain me how to achieve the required output for the suggested situation? 

Many thanks.

Comment: @DevendraMishra If the duplication of records will only depend upon Date and Dialogue values then it doesn't matter that how many columns you have in your dataframe..also we are checking rows values so it has nothing to do with number of columns...so it will work in n no of columns